# I need to update the graphics panel so the user can view the outcome

Tags: java, swing, graphics, panel, turtle-graphics

Right, so I've been given this new project where I have to create one of those turtle programs were the user inputs 'forward 10' and the turtle paints a line on the screen. We were given a big chunk of code to start off with which took a bit of the fun out of it and I also cant fully get my head around how to update what the actual graphics panel. Here's the code we were given:

```
`import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 * Represents the graphics display panel within the turtle program. This panel contains an image which is updated to reflect user commands.
 * 
 * @author mdixon
 * 
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel {

    int currentX = 0,currentY = 0;
    JTextField commandLine;

    /**
     * The default BG colour of the image.
     */
    private final static Color BACKGROUND_COL = Color.DARK_GRAY;

    /**
     * The underlying image used for drawing. This is required so any previous drawing activity is persistent on the panel.
     */
    private BufferedImage image;

        /**
     * Draw a line on the image using the given colour.
     * 
     * @param color
     * @param x1
     * @param y1
     * @param x2
     * @param y2
     */
    public void createLine(int x2, int y2) {

        System.out.println("current x position: " + currentX + "\ncurrent y position: " + currentY);

        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();       
        g.drawLine(currentX, currentY, x2, y2);
        //g.drawString("bloop" , currentX, currentY);
        currentX = x2;
        currentY = y2;

        }

    /**
     * Clears the image contents.
     */
    public void clear() {

        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

        g.setColor(BACKGROUND_COL);

        g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(),  image.getHeight());



    }
    public void setColour(Color colour){
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

        g.setColor(colour);
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        // render the image on the panel.
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */


    GraphicsPanel() {



        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));

        image = new BufferedImage(500, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        // Set max size of the panel, so that is matches the max size of the image.
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));

        clear();
        createLine(currentX + 100,currentY); //THIS WORKS AND  UPDATES THE GRAPHICS PANEL

    }
}`
```

I have already done some changes to it but only minor.
From a different panel which contains a `JtextField` and a `JButton`

So I call the other panel using this:

`GraphicsPanel graphic = new GraphicsPanel();
graphic.createLine(graphic.currentX + 100,graphic.currentY);`

I know this actually gets to `createLine` because I added a console output which shows the change in current x and y positions.

So yeah, If anybody can help with updating the graphics panel when calling it from a different panel it would be greatly appriciated.
Update to code:
Main:

```
`
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Turtle");
        frame.setSize(525, 375);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        WindowsPanel Window = new WindowsPanel();
        frame.setJMenuBar(Window.createMenuBar());
        frame.setContentPane(Window.createContentPane());

        GraphicsPanel panel = new GraphicsPanel(); // creates panel
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER); // adds panel to frame

        CommandPanel panel1 = new CommandPanel(); // creates panel
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // adds panel to frame

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}


import java.awt.Component;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.swing.*;
    public class CommandPanel extends JPanel {
        GraphicsPanel graphic = new GraphicsPanel();

        private JTextField commandLine;

        private JButton commandProcess;

        CommandPanel() {

            add(commandLine = new JTextField(40), Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);

            add(commandProcess = new JButton("Submit Command"),
                    Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);

            commandProcess.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                            String commands = commandLine.getText();
                            try{
                            String[] userCommand = new String[2];
                            userCommand = commands.split(" ");

                            String action = userCommand[0];
                            int amount = Integer.parseInt(userCommand[1]);

                            switch (action) {
                            case ("forward"):

                                        newX = graphic.currentX + amount;
                                        newY = graphic.currentY - amount; 
                                        graphic.createLine(newX,newY);
                                        break;
                            case ("blue"):
                                graphic.setColour(Color.BLUE);
                            break;
                            default:
                                System.out.println("Invalid command!");
                            } 
                            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e1){
                                System.out.println("both sides of the command mus be inputted");
                            }
                        }

                    });

        }
    }

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 * Represents the graphics display panel within the turtle program. This panel contains an image which is updated to reflect user commands.
 * 
 * @author mdixon
 * 
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel {

    int currentX = 0,currentY = 0;

    /**
     * The default BG colour of the image.
     */
    private final static Color BACKGROUND_COL = Color.DARK_GRAY;

    /**
     * The underlying image used for drawing. This is required so any previous drawing activity is persistent on the panel.
     */
    BufferedImage image;

        /**
     * Draw a line on the image using the given colour.
     * 
     * @param color
     * @param x1
     * @param y1
     * @param x2
     * @param y2
     */
    public void createLine(int x2, int y2) {
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();       
        g.drawLine(currentX, currentY, x2, y2);

        currentX = x2;
        currentY = y2;

        }

    /**
     * Clears the image contents.
     */
    public void clear() {

        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

        g.setColor(BACKGROUND_COL);

        g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(),  image.getHeight());



    }
    public void setColour(Color colour){
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

        g.setColor(colour);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);
        // render the image on the panel.
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */


    GraphicsPanel() {



        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));

        image = new BufferedImage(500, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        // Set max size of the panel, so that is matches the max size of the image.
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));

        clear();

        currentX = 200;
        currentY = 200;

    }
}
```

`
All the valid code, should work with copy/paste

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: `public void paint(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g); g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g); g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);`

Comment: @Paul I added `graphic.repaint();` with no noticeable effect to the code
@AndrewThompson How would I call `paintComponent` and what parameters should I pass through to it?

Comment: *"How would I.."*  Where's that MCVE?

Comment: @AndrewThompson What peremeters would be passed into `paintComponent` when I call it from a panel? (Better?)

Comment: *"What peremeters would be passed into paintComponent when I call it from a panel?"*  Give me code I can copy/paste and work with, and I might devote more attention to this.  As it is, that code seen above needs imports and a `main(String[])` to put it on-screen to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Just updated question with the valid code that can be copy/paste, any look into my dilemma greatly appreciated.

Comment: An MCVE needs to be *one* source file, not 4!  How hard is it to understand the concept of 'make it easy for people to help'?!?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I hope this is what you meant by one source file, question updated again. I'm new to this site so not really sure on the rules atc.
If this is not  what you meant then don't worry about it and thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you copy/paste that file, then *without changes* compile it and run the code?  The answer to that answers the question 'is it an MCVE?'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I didn't see anywhere to actually upload a file, got it sorted now anyway, turns out I was creating a new `graphicsPanel()` not calling the original one that displays the output. Where is the option to to upload a file for future reference? screenshot would be nice, thanks Andrew for your persistent responses :)